# Strange empty grey box appears when touching View near top of my screen

Tags: ios, swift

A button near the top of my View is no longer clickable when I have Views with lots of padding or spacers on my page. When I reduce the padding, I am able to click the button, but only the bottom half of its image (80p tall). The top half still gives me the weird box that shows up.

It seems that the more padding / spacing I have, the further up my button goes on the screen (which is desirable), however, the button cannot be clicked above a certain y coordinate of my screen.

Has anyone seen this before? What does this empty box mean? My only guess is that its the NavigationView interfering with getting the touch, as a similar grey box occurs if I hold the back button down without releasing it.

[image: Strange box that pops up in middle of my screen]

Comment: Did you set some Accessibility settings in your device? If you use the Debug View Hierarchy tool of XCode when it appears, can you locate it?

Comment: Good insight! I have larger text enabled on my device and it seems like Nav Bar doesn't like that. When disabling larger text in Accessibility, the issue goes away. I am not sure what to do next, as I would like to keep the app accessible, but I do not know how to resolve this strange behavior.

Comment: Additionally, the grey box does not show up in the Debug View Hierarchy tool